# How to pass default ant settings when using ant from prompt?

Tags: eclipse, ant, exec, command-prompt

In a project there is an ant build.xml file which for example concats and minifies JS resources. I'm using a grunt task which watches the files to be minified and then runs this task (I'm using the grunt [Exec Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-exec)):

```
exec: {
    'run_build_script': 'cd <navigate to the build script directory> && ant'
}
```

After comparing the generated scripts I noticed that umlauts aren't encoded correctly. For example ä becomes Ã¤

Is there a way to use the same settings like in eclipse? I also tried this line:

```
ant -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

but it didn't work. Does anyone know what this is causing and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass default parameters into build.xml, I would recommend to have them hard-coded in build.xml:

```
<property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
```

You can overwrite this property by passing the property value externally.

```
ant -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Make sure you execute ant from the proper directory. A better way than changing workdir and running ant is passing `-f <path to build.xml>` to ant (however make sure not to use relative paths then). For debugging, you can use the `-v` flag which enables verbose mode. Thus the full command line would look like: `ant -f <path to build.xml> -v -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Comment: Thank you. But as written above I already tried this line and unfortunately it didn't help. I don't know what is causing the different output. There must be any other difference within the global ant configuration and the eclipse build-in ant configuration.

Comment: The aim of my answer was to show you the `-v` flag, so you can verify the `-D`-injected parameter is really applied.

Comment: And to show how to provide the ant script with a default value of the property ;)